# Change selection color on view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nstableview

Standard highlighting color in OS X applications is blue.

Is it possible to change it to another color, e.g. gray?

Note that I am using the new view-based `NSTableView` available starting from OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Since you're using the view based NSTableView, you can subclass NSTableRowView, feed it to the table delegate method `- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row;`, then customize your selection in the row view class.

Here's an example:

```
- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (self.selectionHighlightStyle != NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone) {
        NSRect selectionRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 2.5, 2.5);
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:.65 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:.82 alpha:1.0] setFill];
        NSBezierPath *selectionPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:selectionRect xRadius:6 yRadius:6];
        [selectionPath fill];
        [selectionPath stroke];
    }
}
```

Comment: [WWDC 2011 session 120 "View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) gives a similar example, and also describes how to implement different colours depending on whether the table is firstResponder / "active selection" / "emphasized" or not.

Comment: It seems that if the table view is declared as a _source list_ `drawSelectionInRect:` is not called at all on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Only when a table is declared as a _regular_ table will this happen on Yosemite.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, this also overrides the background color of the "blurred" state of the table (like when you select a row, then click into an `NSTextField` somewhere else in your UI). This background color remains in place but the text goes dark. This doesn't look good if you use a dark highlight color. Any idea how to let the table use its default gray for the "blurred" table state?

Comment: @Dev's comment is correct and should be added to the accepted answer.

Comment: [View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/120/)

Answer (score 24):

Here is James Chen's solution in Swift 3. I've also added the delegate method.

```
class MyNSTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if self.selectionHighlightStyle != .none {
            let selectionRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 2.5, 2.5)
            NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.65, alpha: 1).setStroke()
            NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.82, alpha: 1).setFill()
            let selectionPath = NSBezierPath.init(roundedRect: selectionRect, xRadius: 6, yRadius: 6)
            selectionPath.fill()
            selectionPath.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

NSTableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
    return MyNSTableRowView()
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the following code in response to the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol `tableViewSelectionDidChange`:

Get the `NSTableRowView` for the selected row and call the method `setEmphasized` on it. 
When `setEmphasized` is set to YES you get the blue highlight, when NO you get the gray highlight.

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

     NSInteger selectedRow = [myTableView selectedRow];
     NSTableRowView *myRowView = [myTableView rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
     [myRowView setEmphasized:NO];
}
```

Comment: This gives a dancing effect of blue then gray... bad user experience.

Comment: This solution is not work when we click on the row first time. from second click it will work.

Comment: if you use same code while SelectionIsChanging method, it works for the first click too

Comment: if I minimize application and open it again it still show blue color

Answer (score 6):

Some modifications to **Jean-Pierre** answer

Use the following code in response to the NSTableViewDelegate protocol tableViewSelectionDidChange:

Get the NSTableRowView for the selected row and call the method setEmphasized on it. When setEmphasized is set to YES you get the blue highlight, when NO you get the gray highlight.

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

 NSInteger selectedRow = [myTableView selectedRow];
 NSTableRowView *myRowView = [myTableView rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
[myRowView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular];
[myRowView setEmphasized:NO];
}
```

And to avoid dancing effect of blue then gray set

```
[_tableView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];
```

Comment: I works , but it I minimize application and open it again, it again it blue

Answer (score 3):

When using Swift you can do this on 10.10 for view based Cells

Subclass the `NSTableCellView` and implement this:

```
//override to change background color on highlight
override var backgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyle{
    //check value when the style was setted
    didSet{
        //if it is dark the cell is highlighted -> apply the app color to it
        if backgroundStyle == .Dark{
            self.layer!.backgroundColor = yourColor
        }
        //else go back to the standard color
        else{
            self.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `NSTableView` highlight style must be set to `Regular` if it is on `SourceList` it will cause some strange clipping.

This is not the cleanest solution but it works good on yosemite

Comment: It doesn't work. 10.10; view based cell; nstablecellview subclass with your code (but i had to use ? instead of ! after 'layer', otherwise i get crash); regular highlight style.

Comment: This works except when you have space between your cells. The default highlight color shows behind the cell backgrounds. Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/QzMu1I *(Xcode 8.3.3, Swift 3.1)*

Answer (score 3):

I've mixed all methods described before and got code that exactly do what I want.

- Selection not change color of textfields inside;
- Rows remember selection and color of one;
- Any strange outer borders and other leftovers appear.

  ```
  class AudioCellView: NSTableRowView {

      override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
          super.draw(dirtyRect)
          self.wantsLayer = true
          self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
      }

      override var isEmphasized: Bool {
          set {}
          get {
              return false
          }
      }

      override var selectionHighlightStyle: NSTableView.SelectionHighlightStyle {
          set {}
          get {
              return .regular
          }
      }

      override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
          if self.selectionHighlightStyle != .none {
              let selectionRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 2.5, 2.5)
              NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.85, alpha: 0.6).setFill()
              let selectionPath = NSBezierPath.init(rect: selectionRect)
              selectionPath.fill()
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, set emphasized attribute to false, but do it in the custom NSTableRowView class to avoid side effects (like dancing color effect):

```
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
       super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
       self.emphasized = false

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there is an option available to change this coz the documentation says three selection style and the default style in regular is blue, look at the image below.. you need to send it a message which I cant figure out as I have never developed apps for mac before.. hoping this helps...!

[image]

Comment: Hello, `selectionHighlightStyle` _has_ the value `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular`, but I don't know *how* to tell it how to use the _alternate_ or _secondary_ selected color...

Comment: The blue color is shown when the tableview is in focus. If not in focus gray color is displayed. There is no simple method to change the selection color.

Comment: That would make too much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So I do know that it already has an accepted answer, but for anyone like me working with an `NSOutlineView` and has `.selectionHighlightStyle = .sourceList` can use this code to make the selection grey. This method will not flicker when changing the selection and will also stay grey if the app is minimised.

NSTableView/NSOutlineView Delegate:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: Any) -> NSTableRowView?
{
     let row : CustomRowView = CustomRowView.init()
     row.identifier = "row"

     return row
}
```

And then create a new `CustomRowView.swift` file with this:

```
class CustomRowView : NSTableRowView
{
    override var isEmphasized: Bool {
        get { return self.isEmphasized }
        set(isEmp) { self.isEmphasized = false }
    }
}
```

This will keep the selection grey at all times.

Comment: This solution will obviously result in a stack overflow. You are setting the `isEmphasized` property in the setter of the `isEmphasized` property. Simply use the setter to set a private variable instead. With this minor change the solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find this in IB either. The answers above that tell you to set this in the tableview **delegate** tableViewSelectionDidChange: do work, but the disadvantage is that you (I) still see a brief blue flicker on selection when you select the row.

I do the setEmphasized:NO in the **datasource**: tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:

```
NSTableRowView *rowView = [tableView rowViewAtRow:row makeIfNecessary:YES];
[rowView setEmphasized:NO];
```

So this setting is applied before any selection is made, and the blue never appears. Subclassing seems over the top for this problem.

EDIT1: the blue selection returns if you've scrolled and clicked around in the table, or went to another Application, and returned, so my suggestion is to do the [rowView setEmphasized:NO]; procedure in **both** the delegate **and** the datasource. The brief blue flicker still happens now and then though. (macOS 10.15.7 Catalina)

EDIT2: [View based NSTableView selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191413/view-based-nstableview-selection-highlighting) suggests to add:

```
tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone;
```

That seems to get rid of the blue selection completely, even without fiddling with setEmphasized!

EDIT 3(final): You can set this in IB after all, it's the setting "Highlight", under "Style", above the checkbox "Alternating rows". Set to "None", et voila.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to subclass `NSTableView`, and rewrite the functions below in order to change the alternating colors.

- `(void) drawRow: (NSInteger) row clipRect: (NSRect) clipRect`
- `(void) drawBackgroundInClipRect: (NSRect) clipRect` ** This one to change the main and alternate color **

Use a for loop and insert this conditional `(i % 2 == 0)` to detect odd and even rows.

Comment: To clarify, this is not the correct answer for view-based NSTableviews which the question was asking about.  You should only override the above for cell based.

Answer (score -3):

This is Jean-Pierre's answer in Swift3:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
    { 
        index = tableView.selectedRow
        let rowView = tableView.rowView(atRow: index, makeIfNecessary: false)
        rowView?.isEmphasized = false
...
```

It has the two limitations listed above -- first click doesn't work, second click does. And, there is a "dancing effect". I don't mind the first and actually like the second.

Answer (score -4):

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [tblCategory enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock:^(NSTableRowView *rowView, NSInteger row){
        CustomMainCell *cellView = [rowView viewAtColumn:0];
        if(rowView.selected){
            cellView.txtFieldTitle.textColor=[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:245.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }else{
            cellView.txtFieldTitle.textColor=[NSColor whiteColor];
        }
    }];
}
```

[tblCategory setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];

Answer (score -4):

```
  Use this Notification for NSTableView:

          - (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
            {

                 //You Logic stuff
             }
```