# How to change the selection color of a sidebar?

Tags: applescript-objc

Is there any way to change the selection color of a sidebar item?
For example the default color of macOS 10.14.x dark theme is blue, would it be possible to change this color?
I took a look here: [Cocoa osx NSTableview change row highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461362/cocoa-osx-nstableview-change-row-highlight-color)
but I had difficulty translating to Applescript, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Is your table view cell or view based, and what have you done so far?  What exactly are you having trouble translating?

Comment: hey @red_menace, It's based on table view cell, to be honest I don't know what part of objective-c code fits in my script and where it fits, and how it should proceed.

Comment: @red_menace, can you point me a way?

Comment: I had to dig up an old table view sample app I had lying around to test a bit so I wouldn't embarrass myself too much, but my answer should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try, but to let you know I'm following exactly @Ted Wrigley answer in this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384941/how-to-use-a-sidebar-with-applescript?noredirect=1#comment101362561_57384941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample or MCVE project it is going to be tricky providing a drop-in solution.  The topics and answers you linked to are overriding the **NSTableView** or **NSTableRowView** classes, so I can give you a generic solution for that.  Subclassing in AppleScriptObjC can be a bit of a pain, depending on what you need to reference, but is fairly straightforward.  Essentially you are putting a custom class in between the regular class and your application, where you can intercept the various standard method calls.

For a **cell-based table view** example, add a new empty file to your project by using the **File > New > File...** menu item.   The name of the _file _isn't important (e.g. `TableViewHighlight.applescript` or whatever), the name of the *script* is what will be used by Xcode.  Here I am using `MyTableView` for the class name and referencing a `tableView` outlet property from the AppDelegate:

```
script MyTableView -- the name of your custom class

    property parent : class "NSTableView" -- the parent class to override
    property tableView : a reference to current application's NSApp's delegate's tableView
    property highlightColor : a reference to current application's NSColor's greenColor -- whatever

    # set the row highlight color
    on drawRow:row clipRect:clipRect
        if tableView's selectedRowIndexes's containsIndex:row then -- filter as desired
            highlightColor's setFill()
            current application's NSRectFill(tableView's rectOfRow:row)
        end if
        continue drawRow:row clipRect:clipRect -- super
    end drawRow:clipRect:

    # set the highlight color of stuff behind the row (grid lines, etc)
    on drawBackgroundInClipRect:clipRect
        highlightColor's setFill()
        current application's NSRectFill(clipRect)
        continue drawBackgroundInClipRect:clipRect -- super
    end drawBackgroundInClipRect:

end script
```

In the **Interface Editor**, use the **Identity Inspector** to set the class of your table view to the `MyTableView` class.  Finally, in your table view setup set its highlighting to none, since it will be done by your subclass (again, assuming a `tableView` outlet is connected to the table view):

```
    tableView's setSelectionHighlightStyle: current application's NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone
```

For a **view-based table view** example, the process is similar, but **NSTableRowView** is the one to subclass. Here the name of the script/class I am using will be `MyTableRowView`:

```
script MyTableRowView -- the name of your custom class

    property parent : class "NSTableRowView" -- the parent class to override
    property highlightColor : a reference to current application's NSColor's redColor -- whatever

    # draw the selected row
    on drawSelectionInRect:dirtyRect
        continue drawSelectionInRect:dirtyRect
        highlightColor's setFill()
        current application's NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    end drawSelectionInRect:

end script
```

In the **Interface Editor**, set the table view's highlight to regular using the **Attributes Inspector**, and add a `tableView:rowViewForRow:` method to the table view's delegate:

```
on tableView:tableView rowViewForRow:row
    set rowIdentifier to "MyTableRow"
    set myRowView to tableView's makeViewWithIdentifier:rowIdentifier owner:me
    if myRowView is missing value then
        set myRowView to current application's MyTableRowView's alloc's initWithFrame:current application's NSZeroRect
        myRowView's setIdentifier:rowIdentifier
    end if
    return myRowView
end tableView:rowViewForRow:
```

There are other options, of course, but that should get you started, and help with translating some of those Objective-C answers/examples.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Qsfj6F3, ops, I think I did not understand well, I will leave the link to the project: https://www.sendspace.com/file/8z3tim

Comment: I understood from your response to my original comment that your table view was cell based, but in your sample it is view-based, so I'll have to make some changes.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No problem, but this is why building applications is a bit off-topic here - it tends to get too complex and is hard to encapsulate into a single topic, especially if you are using the Interface Editor with a lot of bindings.  You will generally have better luck if you can provide a minimal sample demonstrating your specific issue.

Comment: Is there any possibility of using table view's highlighting as Source List?

Comment: would you put the selection a little transparent?
decreasing opacity?

Comment: The opacity can be changed, for example `NSColor's colorWithSRGBRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5`, but any background color would start showing through.  The highlighting example doesn't have the same effect when drawing cell backgrounds, so you would need to play with the header attributes if you are looking at matching the table view background.

Comment: Thanks for your help!