# How to change the colour of selected row in NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsview

I have a view based NSTableView where each row is NSView. When user clicks on any row it should have rounded corner and colour. 
I need to achieve something like -

[image]

Here trash is selected row.
I found one solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HoverTableDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011082), But it is NSTableRowView Based solution, not NSView based.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color

Comment: I am using NSTableView, not UITableView.

Comment: My apologies, I was flashed by the screenshot

Comment: Now for NSTableView, look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463871/change-selection-color-on-view-based-nstableview

Comment: There is nothing to apologies :) But I am still looking for solution.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have to make my view Subclass of NSTableRowView, NSView will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the NSTableRowView solution a problem? In view-based tables, each row consists of two main views:

- An **NSTableCellView**. Since table views can have multiple columns, each row contains an NSTableCellView for each column in the table.
- An **NSTableRowView**. This is displayed behind the NSTableCellViews for each row in the table. By default, this is the view which displays the blue background.

There's a good diagram showing this in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH2-SW4).

As such, creating your own NSTableRowView which draws the red/orange background would be a good way of achieving what you want as it sits behind the NSTableCellViews for the row. You can set these rows up and return them in the `- tableView:rowViewForRow:` NSTableViewDelegate method.

Comment: Problem with NSTableRowView is that [reloadDataForRowIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:) is not calling TableDelegate's rowViewForRow method. For NSTableRowView Based approach I have to do complete table reload(reloadData()).