# Change highlight color of NSTableView selected row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, xamarin.mac, nstablecellview

how to change NSTable selected row background color?

here is good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265662/how-to-change-color-of-uitableviewcell-when-selecting?answertab=active#tab-top), but it is for uitable view .

For now,what I see is that I can change selected hilight style :

```
MyTAble.SelectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.Regular;
```

But here is only 3 options;

```
None = -1L,
        Regular,
        SourceList
```

I have tried following solution :

```
patientListDelegate.SelectionChanged += (o, e) => {
                        var r = PatientTableView.SelectedRow;
                        var v = PatientTableView.GetRowView (r, false);
                        v.Emphasized = false;
                    };
```

It works normally , but if I minimize and then open application again , still shows blue color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in objective-c

[Change selection color on view-based NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463871/change-selection-color-on-view-based-nstableview)

Here is c# implementation:

inside delegate :

```
public override NSTableRowView CoreGetRowView (NSTableView tableView, nint row)
        {
            var rowView = tableView.MakeView ("row", this);
            if (rowView == null) {
                rowView = new PatientTableRow ();
                rowView.Identifier = "row";
            }
            return rowView as NSTableRowView;
        }
```

and custom row :

```
public class PatientTableRow : NSTableRowView
    {
        public override void DrawSelection (CGRect dirtyRect)
        {
            if (SelectionHighlightStyle != NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.None) {

                NSColor.FromCalibratedWhite (0.65f, 1.0f).SetStroke ();
                NSColor.FromCalibratedWhite (0.82f, 1.0f).SetFill ();

                var selectionPath = NSBezierPath.FromRoundedRect (dirtyRect, 0, 0);

                selectionPath.Fill ();
                selectionPath.Stroke ();
            }
        }
    }
```